# Why is the scalar line integral independent of the path direction while the single valued integral is dependent on the path direction?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

We know that $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\:dx = -\int_{b}^{a}f(x)\:dx$$
However, when it comes to scalar line integrals, we know that $$\int_{C}g(x,y)\:dr=\int_{-C}g(x,y)\:dr$$
where $-C$ represents the parameterisation in the reverse direction.

Doesn't this create a paradox? Suppose I have two parameterisations
$$p_1(t)=[t\;\;0]$$
$$p_2(t)=[(a+b-t)\;\;0]$$

where $a \leq t \leq b$

So $p_1(t)$ runs from $a$ to $b$ whereas $p_2(t)$ runs from $b$ to $a$. Hence,
$$\int_{a}^{b}g(t,0)\:dt=\int_{a}^{b}g(a+b-t,0)\:dt$$

The integral on the LHS says that the function $g(t,0)$ (which is now a single variable function), is being integrated from $a$ to $b$. The integral on the RHS says that the function $g(t,0)$ is being integrated from $b$ to $a$. According to the first equation I have mentioned, shouldn't these two be of opposite signs?

I understand the mathematical derivation of why the path direction doesn't matter. However, I am having a gap in intuition while comparing to the single variable case.

Comment: Hello! Mohit Kumar. I don't understand your confusion. Can you be more precise? In mathematics there is no room for contradictions.

Comment: Read this:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3772255/on-the-derivation-of-line-integrals/3772529#3772529

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I'm not quite sure if I caught the connection between your answer on that page... Does that mean to say that these are mere definitions?

Comment: Yes. You have not defined $dr$, whether you mean $ds$ or $d\vec{r}$.

Comment: Ah. So is it right to say that the two scalar line integrals are equal because we are defining $dr$ in a particular way? Whereas in the single valued derivative the $dx$ remains the same? I'm still not very comfortable with this notion.

Comment: They are two different integrals. When you do $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ you are working out an integral with orientation. Its generalisation would be the integral of a 1-form $\alpha$ over a curve $C$, viz. $\int_C \alpha$, with $\alpha = f(x)dx + 0dy$, the line integral is meant not meant for 1-forms, but scalar functions on the plane, and it is invariant under reversing parametrisation.

Comment: @Logos All right that makes sense. I am not well versed with one-forms and the like but what I did understand is that drawing a direct comparison between the line integral and the plain vanilla integral is incorrect. Due to the difference that you mentioned, the first doesn't care about orientation while the latter cares about orientation. Thanks!